# In C++, is a 2D array slower in overall operations than a 1D array that behaves like a 2D array?

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, 2d

I just want to ask which is better to implement in terms of performance and efficiency when dealing with 2D arrays, and possibly code complexity since we need to make a matrix library for our group project.

I have a code below (which I think may not be a good example, and I also have a limited ram that's why)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

int main(){

    auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto arr2d = new unsigned long long int[10000ul][10000ul];

    int cnt = 1;
    for(unsigned long long int i=0; i<10000ul; ++i){
        for(unsigned long long int j=0; j<10000ul; ++j){
            arr2d[i][j] = cnt;
            cnt++;
        }
    }
    auto stop = high_resolution_clock::now();   
    auto duration = duration_cast<microseconds>(stop-start);
    cout<<duration.count()<<endl;

    auto start1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto arr1d = new unsigned long long int[100000000ull];

    int cnt1 = 1;
    for(unsigned long long int i=0; i<10000ul; ++i){
        for(unsigned long long int j=0; j<10000ul; ++j){
            arr1d[(i*10000ul)+j] = cnt1;
            cnt1++;
        }
    }
    auto stop1 = high_resolution_clock::now();  

    auto duration1 = duration_cast<microseconds>(stop1-start1);
    cout<<duration1.count()<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

and it shows that the performance hasn't really have that much of a difference?

can anyone give us an advice with explanation on which route should we take?

Comment: means that the size won't change, so this is a dynamic array?

Comment: uhmmmm... okay so I guess the word static and dynamic has nothing to do with my problem then , I'll edit the title.

Comment: uhhhmm... yeah too tired to implement it.

Comment: There is no single answer to this question. The relative performance of code with a multi-dimensional array (versus accessing elements of a 1D array in a way akin to using a 2D array) depends on the operations done on the array (or the patterns by which elements are accessed and modified). For general-purpose code - which typically does things using varying patterns of access, it's hard to know - the operations may sometimes suit a 1D array and sometimes suit an array of arrays. Not much difference either way if looping to access all elements (even if not completely sequential)

Comment: so you think it's much better to implement 2d arrays then since it's much easier to code for a matrix library?

Comment: while it might not make much difference in your code here, you might see a difference when you allocate memory on the heap instead of the stack, because you do not know the dimensions of your array at compile-time.Once you do that, and allocate separate memory per row/column  you will probably see a difference, as you  have no control  over where the memory was allocated on the heap. In that case allocating a 1D-array (and therefore sequential memory) will probably generate performance benefits.

Comment: @himynameisjm - I didn't suggest that at all.  It depends on the nature of the algorithms that act on the matrix.   For (say) matrix inversion, there are some algorithms that are more easily optimised for a 1D representation (e.g. rows or columns laid contiguously end-to-end) but there are other algorithms that are better suited toward a 2D array (that is explicitly represented as an array of arrays).   There are also sparse matrix representations that are poorly suited to both a 1D or a 2D representation.  You're fishing for a single universal answer, when the real answer is "it depends".

Comment: @Peter I see thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your particular case, both of your for loops are actually accessing the memory sequentially, even in the 2-D array case (due to the memory layout of the 2-D array), so there is no real difference. To see some difference execution speed, try the following pattern:

```
for(unsigned long long int i=0; i<10000ull; ++i){
    for(unsigned long long int j=0; j<10000ull; ++j){
        arr2d[j][i] = 1-1*3+3/4;  // note i and j are switched.
    }
}
```

When you access the memory sequentially, the CPU is smart enough to prefetch the memory content into the CPU's L1 and L2 caches. But in the modified version, the access to the memory is not sequential -- it jumps 10000*8 bytes ahead each time, and the CPU won't be able to prefetch that far ahead, so the code will run slower.

Another thing to note in your code is that the expression `1-1*3+3/4` will actually be precomputed by the compiler because it contains only constants, so your code will become only a series of assignments.

Answer (score 1):

The performance of the two approaches is expected to be identical.

A 2D array, like `unsigned long long int[10000ul][10000ul]` occupies a single contiguous block of memory, the same as a 1D array with the same number of elements, like `unsigned long long int[100000000ull]`. No difference here.

With an eye towards accessing elements in the array, let's simplify the notation by assuming `sizeof(unsigned long long)` is `8`. When you access `arr2d[i][j]`, the compiler adds `(i*10000ul + j)*8` to the starting address of `arr2d` to find that element. When you access `arr1d[(i*10000ul)+j]`, the compiler adds `((i*10000ul)+j)*8` to the starting address of `arr1d` to find that element. No difference here.

There is no difference in the low-level implementation of the two approaches, so you should use whatever is more convenient. **However,** before leveraging this answer, be sure you are using a 2D array (as in `T [M][N]`) and not an array of pointers to arrays (as in `T* [M]`). The notation for using one is often indistinguishable from that for the other, yet the array of pointers uses more memory and does not guarantee that everything is contiguous. Whether or not this measurably affects performance in your code depends on which operations are performed. (While the question does show a true 2D array, future readers may benefit from this caveat.)

Speaking of convenience, you might find that `std::vector` is more convenient than managing memory yourself. If you opt to use a vector, though, you may want to stick with the 1D approach. A nested vector, as in `std::vector< std::vector<unsigned long long int>>`, is analogous to an array of pointers, so you lose the benefits of a single contiguous block of memory.